# Subscribe device token to AWS SNS topic

Tags: android, amazon-sns

I'm a newbie in AWS. I'm developing an android app.

I'm able to store device tokens programmatically in the platform application. Is it possible to subscribe the device token (or endpoint ARN) to the AWS SNS topic(without using console)?

Thanks.
Ashish

Comment: Everything in AWS can be done either through the console, through an API call or through the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). What is your preferred programming language? See: https://aws.amazon.com/tools/#SDKs

Comment: Thanks for the reply.